Implement a custom log target with shared access
I need to implement a custom log target for the env_logger. Another thread running concurrently needs access to the target to process the logged data. My current code doesn't compile because of ownership issues, which I understand, but I couldn't figure out how to fix them.
use std::{thread};
use std::sync::Mutex;

pub struct MyTarget {
    some_value: u64,
    buffer: Mutex<String>,
}

impl std::io::Write for MyTarget {
fn write(&mut self, buf: &[u8]) -> std::io::Result<usize> {
    std::io::stdout().write_all(buf).unwrap();
    Ok(buf.len())
}

fn flush(&mut self) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    Ok(())
}
}

impl MyTarget {
    fn deliver_logs_loop(&mut self) {
        loop {
            // ...
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let dummy_settings = 123;
    let mut target = MyTarget{some_value: dummy_settings, buffer: Mutex::new(String::new())};

    env_logger::Builder::new()
        .target(env_logger::Target::Pipe(Box::new(target)))
        .init();

    thread::spawn(move || {
        target.deliver_logs_loop();
    });
}

The error is:
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `target`
--> src/main.rs:36:19
|
30 |     let mut target = MyTarget{some_value: dummy_settings, buffer: Mutex::new(String::new())};
|         ---------- move occurs because `target` has type `MyTarget`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
33 |         .target(env_logger::Target::Pipe(Box::new(target)))
|                                                   ------ value moved here
...
36 |     thread::spawn(move || {
|                   ^^^^^^^ value used here after move
37 |         target.deliver_logs_loop();
|         ------ use occurs due to use in closure

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0382`.
error: could not compile `playground` (bin "playground") due to 1 previous error

Link to playground

Make it copyable (if viable) or wrap it around a synchronization primitive (like Arc, or Atomic)

Can you explain what you're trying to achieve?  This looks like it might be better implemented using a custom logger, rather than using env_logger.

@trojanfoe I need to output the logs normally and stream them periodically to another system/ process. In order not to have to re-implement all the log formatting etc. I thought using a custom target for the env_logger would be the easiest solution to achieve it.

No, implementing a custom logger is simple and is the way to go.

@trojanfoe How can I reuse all the functionality of env_logger (config using env, filtering, formatting, ...)?

@TedKleinBergman But wouldn't each thread (main and my custom thread) have an independent copy of buffer in MyTarget then?

@gucki You can still use the env_logger filter in your custom logger and implementing the log::Log trait is straight forward.  I simply use let message = record.args().to_string(); to get the message string.

In the end I solved it by decoupling the buffer and flushing logic from the log target:
use std::{thread, time};
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

pub struct MyTarget {
    buffer: Arc<Mutex<Vec<u8>>>,
}

impl std::io::Write for MyTarget {
    fn write(&mut self, buf: &[u8]) -> std::io::Result<usize> {
        let mut buffer = self.buffer.lock().unwrap();
        std::io::stdout().write_all(buf)?;
        buffer.write_all(buf)?;
        Ok(buf.len())
    }

    fn flush(&mut self) -> std::io::Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let buffer = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Vec::new()));
    let target = MyTarget{buffer: Arc::clone(&buffer)};

    env_logger::Builder::new()
        .target(env_logger::Target::Pipe(Box::new(target)))
        .filter_level(log::LevelFilter::Debug)
        .format_timestamp_millis()
        .parse_default_env()
        .init();

    thread::spawn(move || {
        loop {
            {
                let mut a = buffer.lock().unwrap();
                match String::from_utf8(a.to_vec()) {
                    Ok(string) => print!("thread: {:?}\n", string),
                    Err(e) => println!("Error: {}", e),
                }
                a.clear();
            }
            thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(100));
        };
    });

    log::warn!("This is a test!");
    thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(1000));
    log::warn!("Final!");
}

Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=16adf3cf4254eeac31fcdc62164d9244
